# Why this slide images don't run? It is very strange

Tags: javascript, html, slide

I view only the first image. 
I checked every word but I don't find the error.
This is the code:

```
www.jsfiddle.net/4kgg5teg/
```

Thank you, and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

http://jsfiddle.net/4kgg5teg/1/

It was the `setTimeout` you need to pass in the function, not a string of the name. Also the function was nested in the for loop which it didn't need to be.

Comment: I see that in jsfiddle it runs, but in my browser no... why???? the code is the same

Answer (score 0):

In your jsfiddle on line 13

```
 setTimeout("slideit()", 2500);
```

change string "slideit()" to just slideit, like this:

```
 setTimeout(slideit, 2500);
```

You have to specify a function for setTimeout, not a string with a name of the function, like you did

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and simplified your code considerably. There were numerous problems with it, such as your nesting and passing a string to [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout).

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="mainbox">
        <img src="list/1.jpg" id="slide" height="605px" width="800px" />
    </div>
</body>
```

The only change there was making the name attribute into an id. This is a choice of preference; I think it makes the code more readable and reliable. (Instead of [`document.images.slide`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/images) we can now do [`document.getElementById("slide")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) in our JavaScript code.

**JavaScript**

```
var slide, step;

slide = document.getElementById("slide"); 
step = 0;

setInterval(function () {
    slide.src = "list/" + (step+1) + ".jpg";
    step++;
    step %= 7;
}, 2500);
```

As you can see, my code is considerably shorter. The two main changes I made was cutting out the `img` array (which was plain confusing) and using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) instead of `setTimeout` to avoid recursion. Additionally I fixed the references to your images to `list/[img #].jpg` from `img[img #].src` (I got that path from your HTML). Another minor change I made was using the [remainder operator (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder) (also known as modulo operator) instead of the if/else to make `step` "wraparound."

I hope that my revisions solved your problem and more importantly helped you realize how to solve issues like this one in the future.

Best of luck,
pzp

Comment: thank you dude, Your explanarion had been very useful.